# Editable p:dataTable not setting updated values in bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to edit the user data, but I couldn't set the updated values to the manage beans.

I tried to write the values manually in my SQL update and it works, but I out of options now, any help would be appreciated:

XHTML :

```
<p:dataTable id="DT" value="#{Jadmin.messages}" var="o"
             selection="#{Jadmin.selectedUser}" rowKey="#{o.id}"
             style="margin-bottom:20px" editable="true">

    <f:facet name="header">
        Users List
    </f:facet>

    <p:column selectionMode="single" />

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="id" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{o.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="username" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:inputText value="#{o.username}"  />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="password" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{o.password}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="permission" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{o.permission}" />
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton  value="Update" action="#{Jadmin.update}" />

        <p:commandButton value="Delete"
                         action="#{Jadmin.delete}"
                         ajax="false"
                         update=":form:msgs"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Method that updates the database which I think it causing the problem
Java:

```
public static void updateUser(JadminController user) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET username = ?,password =?, permission =? WHERE username = ? ");

        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername()); //updated value should be here
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());//updated value should be here
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getPermission());//updated value should be here
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getUsername());//searching by user for now I will change it to id later
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

JadminController.java

```
package admin_page;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class JadminController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username, password, permission;
    private long id;
    boolean editable;

    public JadminController() {}

    public JadminController(String username, String password, String permission) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

    public void setPermission(String permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }
}
```

Managed Bean:

```
public class JadminBeans implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String username, password, permission;

private JadminController selectedUser;


List<JadminController> userslist = new ArrayList<JadminController>();


public List<JadminController> getMessages() {
    System.out.println("List<JadminController> getMessages()");
    userslist=  JadminDAO.getAllUsers();
    return userslist;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPermission() {
    return permission;
}

public void setPermission(String permission) {
    this.permission = permission;
}


public JadminController getSelectedUser() {
    return selectedUser;
}

public void setSelectedUser(JadminController selectedUser) {
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
}


public void add(){

    JadminController ADDUSER = new JadminController (this.username, this.password ,this.permission);
    userslist.add(ADDUSER);
    JadminDAO.addUser(ADDUSER);
}



public void update(){


    JadminDAO.updateUser(selectedUser);
}


 }
```

Comment: This is not editable datatable. How you could update your model values if you don't have any input element? Where is managed bean code?

Comment: Please check the managed bean above @giaffa86, are you suggesting that I should change the datatable?

Comment: You can find an editable datatable example [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml). IMHO you did a little confusion with architecture pattern, JadminController should contains business logic (something like `updateUser method`), actually it is represents an data transfer object

Comment: and of course, Managed Bean shouldn't never see DAO layer.